# Creating an extension in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am new to Yii. I have a jquery **[file manager](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/)** working with plain PHP script. Now i want to integrate it with Yii Application. The flow is like, from index it will initiate jquery function, which will search for PHP connector script. My problem is, how can i include connector script in Yii so that the Jquery can access it

Comment: you can help by cjuidatepicker it is also wrapper of jquery datepicker. it is not extension but embedded in framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the rest of the extension working, then you can create a controller within this extension's directory to handle any actions for it. Then you can use the URL rules in the configuration to send specific URLs to it.

Answer (score 0):

as of now i did not create any extensions, I put the connector script under assets directory and it just worked fine. I am sure this cannot be the best practice. I would like to get help on creating custom extensions for Yii